# Calculate $ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\cos{\big{(}\pi \sqrt{n^2+n}\big{)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to prove that 
 $$ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\cos{\big{(}\pi \sqrt{n^2+n}\big{)}}=1$$

But this is something that seems highly unlikely to have a limit, but I am probably wrong. Wolfram Alpha says "$0$ to $1$". What does that even mean? How to prove this?

If you could provide only a hint (if this limit exists) so I can finish the task myself.

Comment: Depends on whether $n\in\mathbb N$ or $n\in\mathbb R$. For $n\in\mathbb N$, as is traditional for the variable $n$, there is a limit.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is probably assuming $n\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is not stated in the task whether $n$ is natural number or not.

Comment: Wolfram says [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+cos%28pisqrt%28n%5E2+%2B+n%29%29%2C+n%3Dinfinity).

Comment: Yes, Wolfram is assuming $n\in\mathbb R$, rather than the usual $n\in\mathbb N$. @AaronMaroja

Comment: Slightly relevant: $\cos(\pi\sqrt{1000000^2+1000000})\approx0.00000039$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\cos\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)\\
&=\cos\left(\pi\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+n}-n\right)\right)\\
&=\cos\left(\pi\left(n+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}\right)\right)\\
&=\cos\left(\pi n\right)\cos\left(\pi\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}\right)-\sin\left(\pi n\right)\sin\left(\pi\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}\right)\\
&=(-1)^n\cos\left(\frac\pi{\sqrt{1+1/n}+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\frac\pi{\sqrt{1+1/n}+1}\right)=\cos(\pi/2)=0
$$
we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)=0
$$

Comment: Well this is extremely strange, it's probably a mistake in the textbook, since it explicitly says "prove". Thanks.

Comment: It's definitely not $1$. @Transcendental

Answer (score 4):

The limit is not $1$.

Hint: $n^2+n=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}$.

Show that $$\pi\sqrt{n^2+n}-\pi\left(n+\frac12\right)\to 0.$$

Note that this is an example of an ambiguity in the $\lim$ notation.

If you had instead asked for $\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos\left(\pi\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)$, you'd have no limit. The continuous limit, rather than the sequence limit, is what Wolfram Alpha is computing.

Comment: The limit of $\cos{\pi\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ is $0$ so this probably the misteake

Comment: No, the limit of $(-1)^n\cos \pi\sqrt{n^2+1}$ is $1$, but you have the alternating signs. @pw1822

Comment: soryy i wanted to write 1 :P

Answer (score 1):

Since $$0\leq \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\sqrt{n^2+n} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq\frac{1}{8n}$$
we get that, as long as $n\to +\infty$, $\pi\sqrt{n^2+n}$ gets closer and closer to $\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Since $\cos\left(\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)=-\sin(\pi n)$ and the cosine is a continuous function, the limit is just $\color{red}{0}$.

Comment: No, it is $\leq \frac{n}{2n}$, which isn't useful. You really need to complete the square.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: thanks, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When $n \to \infty$

$$\sqrt{n^2+n} \approx n + \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\cos\left(\pi\left(n+\frac{1}2\right)\right)=0.$$